# ASP.NET Visual Studio Building ErrorEncountered multiple versions of the assembly with GUID

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Hey Just wondering what this is all about, all of a sudden I got this error in visual studio and can no longer built my website

Error   1   Encountered multiple versions of the assembly with GUID 'd01967cc-f8ca-49bd-b7c6-3230cc1a6e86'.  Try pre-importing one of these assemblies. C:\inetpub\wwwroot\website\TlbImp

I have no Idea the file that is referring to, as it does not exist.

Any help would be appreciated